# commitFileFailed during mobileAppContentFile Commit

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I'm working on a JS script (ru that will upload an app to intune.
When I try to commit an app content file to intune I always receive commitFileFailed, and I don't see any reason for that. Is there any way to figure out why it fails?

I think it may be because of the encryption, but I'm not really sure. This is how I encrypted it:

```
const key = Crypto.randomBytes(32);
const hmacKey = Crypto.randomBytes(32);
const iv = Crypto.randomBytes(16);
const cipher = Crypto.createCipheriv('aes256', key, iv);
const hmac = Crypto.createHmac('sha256', hmacKey);
const hash = Crypto.createHash('sha256');

let encrypted = cipher.update(originalFileBuffer);
encrypted = [...encrypted, ...cipher.final()];
const encryptedBuffer = Buffer.from(encrypted);

let encryptedHmac = hmac.update(encryptedBuffer);
let digest = hmac.digest('base64');

hash.update(Buffer.from(originalFileBuffer));
const fileDigest = hash.digest('base64');

const encryptionInfo = {
    fileEncryptionInfo: {
        '@odata.type': 'microsoft.graph.fileEncryptionInfo',
        encryptionKey: Buffer.from(key).toString('base64'),
        macKey: Buffer.from(hmacKey).toString('base64'),
        initializationVector: Buffer.from(iv).toString('base64'),
        mac: digest,
        profileIdentifier: 'ProfileVersion1',
        fileDigest: fileDigest,
        fileDigestAlgorithm: 'SHA256'
    }
};
```

And my encryption info looks like this:

```
{
  "encryptionKey": "5hYywG3rkdeMLSuvW6xyvA==",
  "macKey": "0PVu0l0avph6p2E3HCpHIw==",
  "initializationVector": "UQVtvxe4n28oWrMLz5ei9w==",
  "mac": "hjD5yZnOPFJjgijB4vtdw+6Lh8U3X2Xnp8dOcscv/QI=",
  "profileIdentifier": "ProfileVersion1",
  "fileDigest": "wMlT8MU7Rm0BXzIj8STRCjjye/Hn0UQTqQ9A2eRb41U=",
  "fileDigestAlgorithm": "SHA256"
}
```

And the manifest like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AndroidManifestProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Package>test.android.app</Package>
    <PackageVersionCode>1</PackageVersionCode>
    <PackageVersionName>1.0.0</PackageVersionName>
    <ApplicationName>TestApp.apk</ApplicationName>
    <MinSdkVersion>4</MinSdkVersion>
    <AWTVersion/>
</AndroidManifestProperties>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while you've asked this question, but I'm running into it now as well. Were you able to fix it? And do you remember how?