# uploadState returns commitFileFailed

Tags: ruby, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an app in InTune using the Microsoft Graph REST API. I'm able to create the app, the contentversion, upload a file to Azure Storage, and call the commit action. After that, I'm waiting for uploadState 'commitFileSuccess', but it returns 'commitFileFailed'.

I saw a similar question, but that's assuming the file encryption is wrong:
[commitFileFailed during mobileAppContentFile Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919573/commitfilefailed-during-mobileappcontentfile-commit)

However, I have no clue where the error lies. Is there anybody with experience on this particular subject?
If you need more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I was doing wrong. I used the PowerShell sample from Github as a base to write my own Ruby version, but I overlooked one thing.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/LOB_Application

I was uploading my apk file at once to the azureStorageUri, but I needed to upload it in chunks. After doing that the uploadState got updated to commitFileSuccess.

I will share my Ruby script once I've cleaned it up!